# Webview is showing content from other Webview (multiple webviews in the same app)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have two webviews, loading different content. Sometimes, one webview is showing content from the other webview. It is very strange, I can't understand why.

I checked the official documentation and I can't find any problem of having different webviews on the same application loading different content.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebStorage.html

Should we do something special when managing different webviews in the same application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to clear the Webview data/content before loading new URL.
There is method called as `clearView();` but it is deprecated in API level 18+, so you need to check API version and apply appropriate solution as below.

Check this code.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
   webView.clearView();
} else {
   webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
```

Hope this helps you out. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of options, but I only got it to work when I followed this:

First, when you reload your entire webview (or if you have pieces of it in your layout), before you set the content, set the visibility to GONE.

```
mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then, set the content:

```
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(//My URL);
```

Then, set the visibility to VISIBLE again:

```
mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Sometimes, in early versions of Android, the webview loads a content that is large. Then, when you load a new content that is not so large, the webview doesn't stretch itself to the new content, and the page keep always the large size that has been put on it.
This strategy worked fine here, to solve both issues (yours and this last one).

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to do something special to manage different Webviews in the same App, even in the same Activity layout.
Just remember, as [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), that multiple Webviews share the same cache per App.